# is there any solution to get data from different api at once

Tags: angular8

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokemonDataService {

  pokeData = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'
  pokeUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getPoke(){
    return this.http.get<any>(this.pokeUrl)
  }
  getData(){
      for(let i=1;i<152;i++){
        return this.http.get<any>(this.pokeData+i)
      }
  }
  
}
```

**I want to get data from api https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1, https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2 like this**

Comment: you should look into scrapers, i.e. scrapy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can do this:

```js
getData(): Observable<any[]>{
  const observables: Array<Observable<any>> = [];
  for(let i=1;i<152;i++){
    const obs: Observable<any> = this.http.get<any>(this.pokeData+i)
        .pipe(catchError(err => of({})));
    observables.push(obs);
  }

  // returns when all the observables emit
  return forkJoin(observables);
}
```

and you can use like this:

```js
getData().subscribe((pokemons: any[]) => console.log(pokemons.length));
```